# I can't echo certain variables?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to validate my form using php. The thing is I have 2 radio button's and 3 select.When I echo out my code below nothing happens, no error is shown but the variables do not echo.
 if I change my code and exclude"$sex,$month,$day & $year" it echos. I am wondering if I should use jquery to validate the select and radio fields? or is there a better structure in php to do this?

My html is this:

```
<form id="fleft" action="signup.php" method="POST">

    <input type="text" id="box1" name="username" maxlength="30"/><br><br>

    <input type="text" id="box2" name="FirstName" maxlength="30"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <input type="text" id="box3" name="LastName" maxlength="30"/><br><br>

    <input type="text" id="box4" name="Emailadd"  maxlength="50"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <input type="text" id="box5" name="reEmailadd" maxlength="50"/><br><br>

    <input type="password" id="box6" name="Password" maxlength="30"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <input type="password" id="box7" name="rePassword"  maxlength="30"/><br><br>

    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"><label id="male" for="Male">&nbsp; Male &nbsp; &nbsp;</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"><label id="female" for="female">&nbsp;Female<br><br>

    <label id="d_o_b" for="Date Of Birth">Date Of Birth:</label><br>
        <select name="Month">
            <option value="Month">Month</option>
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option value="February">February</option>
            <option value="March">March</option>
            <option value="April">April</option>
            <option value="May">May</option>
            <option value="June">June</option>
            <option value="July">July</option>
            <option value="August">August</option>
            <option value="September">September</option>
            <option value="October">October</option>
            <option value="November">November</option>
            <option value="December">December</option>
        </select>
        <select name="Day">
            <option value="Day">Day</option>
            <option value="01">01</option>
            <option value="02">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            <option value="06">06</option>
            <option value="07">07</option>
            <option value="08">08</option>
            <option value="09">09</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
        <select name="Year">
            <option value="Year">Year</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="1998">1998</option>
            <option value="1997">1997</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1993">1993</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="1989">1989</option>
            <option value="1988">1988</option>
            <option value="1987">1987</option>
            <option value="1986">1986</option>
            <option value="1985">1985</option>
            <option value="1984">1984</option>
            <option value="1983">1983</option>
            <option value="1982">1982</option>
            <option value="1981">1981</option>
            <option value="1980">1980</option>
            <option value="1979">1979</option>
            <option value="1978">1978</option>
            <option value="1977">1977</option>
            <option value="1976">1976</option>
            <option value="1975">1975</option>
            <option value="1974">1974</option>
            <option value="1973">1973</option>
            <option value="1972">1972</option>
            <option value="1971">1971</option>
            <option value="1970">1970</option>
            <option value="1969">1969</option>
            <option value="1968">1968</option>
            <option value="1967">1967</option>
            <option value="1966">1966</option>
            <option value="1965">1965</option>
            <option value="1964">1964</option>
            <option value="1963">1963</option>
            <option value="1962">1962</option>
            <option value="1961">1961</option>
            <option value="1960">1960</option>
            <option value="1959">1959</option>
            <option value="1958">1958</option>
            <option value="1957">1957</option>
            <option value="1956">1956</option>
            <option value="1955">1955</option>
            <option value="1954">1954</option>
            <option value="1953">1953</option>
            <option value="1952">1952</option>
            <option value="1951">1951</option>
            <option value="1950">1950</option>
            <option value="1949">1949</option>
            <option value="1948">1948</option>
            <option value="1947">1947</option>
```

and my php is this:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['First Name']) && isset($_POST['Last    Name']) && isset($_POST['Emailadd']) && isset($_POST['reEmailadd']) && isset($_POST['Password']) && isset($_POST['rePassword']) && isset($_POST['sex']) && isset($_POST['Month']) && isset($_POST['Day']) && isset($_POST['Year'])){
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $firstname = $_POST['First Name'];
   $lastname = $_POST['Last Name'];
   $emailaddr = $_POST['Emailadd'];
   $reemailadd = $_POST['reEmailadd'];
   $pwd = $_POST['Password'];
   $repwd = $_POST['rePassword'];
   $sex = $_POST['sex'];
   $month = $_POST['Month'];
   $day = $_POST['Day'];
   $year = $_POST['Year'];

if(!empty($username) && !empty($firstname) && !empty($lastname) && !empty($emailaddr) && !empty($reemailadd) && !empty($pwd) && !empty($repwd) && !empty($sex) && !empty($month) && !empty($day) && !empty($year)){
         echo 'ok';
            }else {
                echo 'incorrect';
```

Comment: Firstly make sure you are ending your tags. I see a couple of unclosed tags. Secondly, you cannot have spaces in `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` variables.

Answer (score 1):

Remove Extra space here

```
$firstname = $_POST['First Name'];
                          ^
$lastname = $_POST['Last Name'];
                        ^
```

---

```
$firstname = $_POST['FirstName'];
$lastname = $_POST['LastName'];
```

---

Get array of all `$_POST` variables

```
echo '<pre>',print_r($_POST,true),'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `ini_set("display_errors", "1");` to the very top of your PHP script in order to see if you have any undefined variable notices. Because PHP doesn't require variable initialisation, you can call variables that are empty/null without a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the mistake I made was in my html:

```
<select value="Year">
            <option value="Year">Year</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="1998">1998</option>
            <option value="1997">1997</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1993">1993</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="1989">1989</option>
            <option value="1988">1988</option>
            <option value="1987">1987</option>
            <option value="1986">1986</option>
            <option value="1985">1985</option>
            <option value="1984">1984</option>
            <option value="1983">1983</option>
            <option value="1982">1982</option>
            <option value="1981">1981</option>
            <option value="1980">1980</option>
            <option value="1979">1979</option>
            <option value="1978">1978</option>
            <option value="1977">1977</option>
            <option value="1976">1976</option>
            <option value="1975">1975</option>
            <option value="1974">1974</option>
            <option value="1973">1973</option>
            <option value="1972">1972</option>
            <option value="1971">1971</option>
            <option value="1970">1970</option>
            <option value="1969">1969</option>
            <option value="1968">1968</option>
            <option value="1967">1967</option>
            <option value="1966">1966</option>
            <option value="1965">1965</option>
            <option value="1964">1964</option>
            <option value="1963">1963</option>
            <option value="1962">1962</option>
            <option value="1961">1961</option>
            <option value="1960">1960</option>
            <option value="1959">1959</option>
            <option value="1958">1958</option>
            <option value="1957">1957</option>
            <option value="1956">1956</option>
            <option value="1955">1955</option>
            <option value="1954">1954</option>
            <option value="1953">1953</option>
            <option value="1952">1952</option>
            <option value="1951">1951</option>
            <option value="1950">1950</option>
            <option value="1949">1949</option>
            <option value="1948">1948</option>
            <option value="1947">1947</option>
```

instead it should be:

```
<select name="Year">
            <option value="Year">Year</option>
            <option value="2012">2012</option>
            <option value="2011">2011</option>
            <option value="2010">2010</option>
            <option value="2009">2009</option>
            <option value="2008">2008</option>
            <option value="2007">2007</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
            <option value="2005">2005</option>
            <option value="2004">2004</option>
            <option value="2003">2003</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="1998">1998</option>
            <option value="1997">1997</option>
            <option value="1996">1996</option>
            <option value="1995">1995</option>
            <option value="1994">1994</option>
            <option value="1993">1993</option>
            <option value="1992">1992</option>
            <option value="1991">1991</option>
            <option value="1990">1990</option>
            <option value="1989">1989</option>
            <option value="1988">1988</option>
            <option value="1987">1987</option>
            <option value="1986">1986</option>
            <option value="1985">1985</option>
            <option value="1984">1984</option>
            <option value="1983">1983</option>
            <option value="1982">1982</option>
            <option value="1981">1981</option>
            <option value="1980">1980</option>
            <option value="1979">1979</option>
            <option value="1978">1978</option>
            <option value="1977">1977</option>
            <option value="1976">1976</option>
            <option value="1975">1975</option>
            <option value="1974">1974</option>
            <option value="1973">1973</option>
            <option value="1972">1972</option>
            <option value="1971">1971</option>
            <option value="1970">1970</option>
            <option value="1969">1969</option>
            <option value="1968">1968</option>
            <option value="1967">1967</option>
            <option value="1966">1966</option>
            <option value="1965">1965</option>
            <option value="1964">1964</option>
            <option value="1963">1963</option>
            <option value="1962">1962</option>
            <option value="1961">1961</option>
            <option value="1960">1960</option>
            <option value="1959">1959</option>
            <option value="1958">1958</option>
            <option value="1957">1957</option>
            <option value="1956">1956</option>
            <option value="1955">1955</option>
            <option value="1954">1954</option>
            <option value="1953">1953</option>
            <option value="1952">1952</option>
            <option value="1951">1951</option>
            <option value="1950">1950</option>
            <option value="1949">1949</option>
            <option value="1948">1948</option>
            <option value="1947">1947</option>
```